# Publishing to jointTrajectoryController

Tags: control

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,
I've been wanting to set up my floating gripper with a controller package, like in the example [here](http://wiki.ros.org/joint_trajectory_controller) but I can't seem to find a way to publish a message, for example, for a joint gripper_dummy_prismatic_joint to move by 0.1 distance in gazebo. Below are the .yaml file for gripper control and the rostopic list output. In [gazebo tutorial about connecting ros with gazebo](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_control&cat=connect_ros) it seems very simple, but I can't figure out how to do this with the interface written as on the ros page. I want preferably to send messages by python. I'd post this on the ROS answers, but the site seems to be down for a week now :(

.yaml

```
gripper:
  # Publish all joint states -----------------------------------
  joint_state_controller:
    type: "joint_state_controller/JointStateController"
    publish_rate: 50  

  # Trajectory Controllers ---------------------------------------
  joint_trajectory_controller:
    type: "effort_controllers/JointTrajectoryController"
    joints:
     - gripper_dummy_prismatic_joint
     - gripper_dummy_revolute_joint
     - gripper_joint1
     - gripper_joint2
    gains:
       
       gripper_dummy_prismatic_joint: {p:  6000,  d: 1000 , i: &ki_default 1.0, i_clamp: &ki__clamp_default 2}
       gripper_dummy_revolute_joint: {p: &kp_default 8000 ,  d: &kd_default 25.0 , i: *ki_default, i_clamp: *ki__clamp_default}
       gripper_joint1: {p: *kp_default ,  d: *kd_default , i: *ki_default, i_clamp: *ki__clamp_default}
       gripper_joint2: {p: *kp_default ,  d: *kd_default , i: *ki_default, i_clamp: *ki__clamp_default}
 
    constraints:
       goal_time: &goal_time_constraint 40.0
       stopped_velocity_tolerance: 5.0
          
       gripper_dummy_prismatic_joint:
          goal: &goal_pos_constraint 0.5
          trajectory: &trajectory_pos_constraint 0.5
       gripper_dummy_revolute_joint:
          goal: *goal_pos_constraint
          trajectory: *trajectory_pos_constraint
       gripper_joint1:
          goal: *goal_pos_constraint
          trajectory: *trajectory_pos_constraint
       gripper_joint2:
          goal: *goal_pos_constraint
          trajectory: *trajectory_pos_constraint
       stop_trajectory_duration: 1.0
```

rostopic list:

```
/clock
/gazebo/link_states
/gazebo/model_states
/gazebo/parameter_descriptions
/gazebo/parameter_updates
/gazebo/set_link_state
/gazebo/set_model_state
/gripper/joint_states
/gripper/joint_trajectory_controller/command
/gripper/joint_trajectory_controller/follow_joint_trajectory/cancel
/gripper/joint_trajectory_controller/follow_joint_trajectory/feedback
/gripper/joint_trajectory_controller/follow_joint_trajectory/goal
/gripper/joint_trajectory_controller/follow_joint_trajectory/result
/gripper/joint_trajectory_controller/follow_joint_trajectory/status
/gripper/joint_trajectory_controller/gains/gripper_dummy_prismatic_joint/parameter_descriptions
/gripper/joint_trajectory_controller/gains/gripper_dummy_prismatic_joint/parameter_updates
/gripper/joint_trajectory_controller/gains/gripper_dummy_revolute_joint/parameter_descriptions
/gripper/joint_trajectory_controller/gains/gripper_dummy_revolute_joint/parameter_updates
/gripper/joint_trajectory_controller/gains/gripper_joint1/parameter_descriptions
/gripper/joint_trajectory_controller/gains/gripper_joint1/parameter_updates
/gripper/joint_trajectory_controller/gains/gripper_joint2/parameter_descriptions
/gripper/joint_trajectory_controller/gains/gripper_joint2/parameter_updates
/gripper/joint_trajectory_controller/state
/rosout
/rosout_agg
/tf
/tf_static
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/18135/publishing-to-jointtrajectorycontroller/) by [Fiddle](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3737/fiddle/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 35 on 2017-12-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I've found the answer, it was rather trivial,

```
allow_partial_joints_goal: true
```

needs to be added to the yaml file, then I can publish the messages through

```
rostopic pub /gripper/joint_trajectory_controller/command trajectory_msgs/JointTrajectory
```

then I can specify which joint I want to move.

---

Originally posted by [Fiddle](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3737/fiddle/) with karma: 35 on 2017-12-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0